# Cube root of a convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a real sequence converging to $x$. Then how the proof starts for $x_n^{1/3}$ converges to $x^{1/3}$.

Attempt:
When $x=0$, proof is clear, For the other case,
I got that $$|x_n^{1/3}-x^{1/3}|=\frac{|x_n-x|}{|x_n^{2/3}+x_nx+x^{2/3}|}$$
How to proceed?
Can we say after some stage $|x_n^{2/3}+x_nx+x^{2/3}|>\delta>0$  for a fixed $\delta$?

Comment: WLOG assume $x>0$; then eventually $x_n>0$ as well, and then the denominator is at least $x^{2/3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on Greg's comment, you need to split your problem into two other cases: $x > 0$ and $x<0$. Suppose $x > 0$. We have that

$$|x_n^{1/3} - x^{1/3}| = \frac{|x_n - x|}{|x_n^{2/3} + (xx_n)^{1/3} + x^{2/3}|}$$

A uniform lower bound needs to be found for the denominator so that the size of $|x_n^{1/3} - x^{1/3}|$ is directly related to $|x_n - x|$ (up to a constant depending only on $\epsilon$ and x).

This is achieved by ensuring the terms $x_n$ are sensibly close to $x$. For example, let $a = \min(x, 1)$; then if $|x_n - x| < a$ we have:

$$x_n^{2/3} + (xx_n)^{1/3} + x^{2/3} > x^{2/3} > 0$$

as $(xx_n)^{1/3}$ will be non-negative. Therefore, given $\epsilon > 0$ we have that:

$$|x_n - x| < \min(a, \epsilon x^{2/3}) \implies |x_n^{1/3} - x^{1/3}| = \frac{|x_n - x|}{|x_n^{2/3} + (xx_n)^{1/3} + x^{2/3}|} < \frac{\epsilon x^{2/3}}{x^{2/3}} = \epsilon$$